# Align Braces of Single Line Methods with clang format

Tags: c++, clang-format

Say I have the following C++ code:

```
class Foo
{
   auto foo() { return 0; } // foo
   auto foofoo() const { return 1000; } // foofoo
   int bar() const { return 42; } // bar
};
```

How can I get clang-format for align the braces (and comments too):

```
class Foo
{
   auto foo()          { return 0;    } // foo
   auto foofoo() const { return 1000; } // foofoo
   int  bar()    const { return 42;   } // bar
   //            ^-----^--------------^  ALIGNED
};
```

(In fact, it would be nice to align consecutive method (`const`) qualifiers as well).

Comment: That is currently not possible with `clang-format`. The best that you can do is `AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true`, and maybe `AligntConsecutiveAssignments: true` which you probably already are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignEscapedNewlines: Align
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: true
```

By placing this .clang-format file in the root directory of your project or adding it to your IDE's clang-format configuration, you can apply the desired formatting to your code.

Comment: Is this a new feature (what changed)? Can you add an example that shows this actually works? Does it handle all the alignment cases above (it is OK if not)? It will make your answer more complete and helpful.