# How can align if statement in cpp with clang?

Tags: c++, clang, coding-style, clang-format

I would like to align the following lines

```cpp
if (_a) { return; }
if (__b) { return; }
if (____c) { return; }
```

with clang-format.

Desired Result:

```cpp
if (_a)     { return; }
if (__b)    { return; }
if (____c)  { return; }
```

I'm using clang formatter with version 13.0.
I've tried

```
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: WithoutElse
```

but i've obtained only aligned of conditions but not body statements.

Comment: I don't know if this works with if statements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53986605/align-braces-of-single-line-methods-with-clang-format

Comment: @NathanOliver unfortunately it doesn't work